# json массив сортировка по дате

Tags: php, json

как сделать группировку по дате(без времени) и выводить все значения по времени к этой дате с такого массива:

```
[{"MIGX_id":"3","datam":"2018-03-12 17:00:00","logo":"xokkej.jpg","namel":"КХЛ","command":"Металлург Магнитогорск - Автомобилист","prog":"П1","koef":"2.04"},
{"MIGX_id":"4","datam":"2018-03-12 22:00:00","logo":"futbol.jpg","namel":"Чемпионат Голландии. Первый дивизион","command":"Утрехт II - НЕК","prog":"Фора 2(-1)","koef":"1.71"},{"MIGX_id":"5","datam":"2018-03-13 22:45:00","logo":"futbol2.png","namel":"Лига Чемпионов УЕФА","command":"Манчестер Юнайтед - Севилья","prog":"П1","koef":"1.7"},
{"MIGX_id":"6","datam":"2018-03-13 22:45:00","logo":"futbol2.png","namel":"Чемпионат Англии. Чемпионшип","command":"Астон Вилла - Куинз Парк Рейнджерс","prog":"П1","koef":"1.77"}]
```

пробовал отсортировать так:

```
$array = json_decode($parent_name['vl'], true);
foreach ($array as $element) {
   $result[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($element['datam']))][] = $element;
}
ksort($result);
```

, но если задавать условие на сравнение даты и времени, выводит как на картинке

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value){
  if ($value[0]['datam'] >= $databegin && $value[0]['datam'] <= $dataend){
    //вывод значений
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[uasort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php) - Сортирует массив, используя пользовательскую функцию для сравнения элементов с сохранением ключей

```
$array = json_decode($parent_name['vl'], true);

uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['datam'] > $b['datam'];
});

foreach($array as $k => $v) { // никаких дополнительных сверок дат не надо!
    //вывод значений
}
```

[пример](http://jdoodle.com/a/pKs)

Comment: сделать вместо ksort?

Comment: да, перед циклом вывода.

Comment: в ответе посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: не надо foreach, uasort делает сортировку заданного массива сам, приводить дату нет нужды

Comment: расписал ответ немного понятнее

Comment: может добавить еще цикл? я не могу сообразить как к каждой дате вывести список значений, а не каждую дату с новой строки

Answer (score 0):

делаю вывод результатов так, но не выводит

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>".date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value['datam']))."</td></tr>";
                        echo '<tr>
                            <td class="flag" style="background-image: url('.$value['logo'].');">
                            </td>
                            <td class="title">
                                <small>'.$value['namel'].'</small>
                                    <span class="time">'.date("H:i", strtotime($value['datam'])).'</span>
                                    <span class="fore">  <ins>'.$value['command'].'</ins></span>
                                    <span class="full"> Прогноз: '.$value['prog'].'</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="coeff main-coeff">
                                <a href="">
                                    '.$value['koef'].'
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]